# Pass context to a method that is declared in the base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scope

I have the following base class:

```
    abstract class DALBase
    {
    protected static EntityName ctx = null;

        protected static EntityName GetCtx()
        {
            return new EntityName ();
        }
    }
```

Here is the class using the base:

```
    public class MyClass : DALBase
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
             using(ctx = GetCtx())
             {
                 Method2(ctx);
             }
         }
         public void Method2(EntityName context) <---- Here I want to avoid using EntityName
         {
              context....
         }
    }
```

Is there a way to pass the context from one method to another without having to use the entity name of EntityName so the only place I have it declared is in the base class? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking.  Why don't you access ctx directly from Method2?

Comment: Because method 1 will already be making calls to the database and method 2 will be shared with other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality you already can do it. I just created an overloaded Method2(), with no parameters, and called ctx from within it with no problem. ctx is already a local variable inherited from DALBase and is accessible from any MyClass methods.

Comment: How does disposal work with it? Instead of having a using statement in method 2, I want to use the same context for both methods.

Comment: your using statement is in method1, not method2. If you're changing your question now than is better to re-post your code with what exactly you want to do that is not quite working.